# Microsoft.AspNet.Identity and Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework in .NET Standard 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-standard, .net-standard-2.0

Background: The project we are wokring on consists of several solutions that share *two libraries*. Everything is written in `.NET Framework 4.6.1` today. A goal for the project has been to adopt `.NET Core` for new projects and being able to run web applications in `Docker`.

With the new release of `.NET Standard 2.1` and the fact that `.NET Framework 4.8` will remain on `.NET Standard 2.0` rather than implement `.NET Standard 2.1` it felt like the right time to start. Immo Landwerth from Microsoft says this:

> But what is also true is that the rate of innovation in .NET Framework
>   has to slow down in order to reduce breakage. In that sense, you
>   should generally expect that most new features will only become
>   available on .NET Core (and derived platforms, such as Xamarin, Mono,
>   and Unity as they build from the same sources as .NET Core).

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/11/05/announcing-net-standard-2-1/

We would like to have access to new features in our new projects but do not want to convert every old project to `.NET Core`. To keep compatibility between `.NET Framework` and `.NET Core` we decided to convert our shared libraries to `.NET Standard 2.0`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard

This worked really well apart from the following dependencies:

**1. System.Net.Http.WebRequestHandler - Solved**

Used for client certificates like this:

```
WebRequestHandler requestHandler = new WebRequestHandler();

//Add certificate if setting exists
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(pushEvent?.CertificateThumbprint?.Thumbprint))
{
    var certificate = certificateService.GetClientCertificate(pushEvent?.CertificateThumbprint?.Thumbprint);
    if (certificate != null)
    {
        requestHandler.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);
    }
}

var client = new HttpClient(requestHandler);
```

I found a NuGet for it but it seems malicious. The package links to Microsoft documentation as Project Site and has misspelled Microsoft as author, Microsfot. Reported it so Microsoft can have a look at it.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/WebRequest.WebRequestHandler/

However it seems we can change `WebRequestHandler` to `HttpClientHandler` to get it working out of the box.

**2. System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging -> CallContext.LogicalGetData - Solved**

Solved here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53211839/3850405

**3. Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUser**

We have a User Model that inherits from `IdentityUser`.

```
public class AppUser : IdentityUser, ICurrentUser
{
    public bool LocalEnvironment { get; set; }

    public Guid? TokenId { get; set; }
}
```

**4. Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager from assembly Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core**

We keep our `UserManager` shared between the projects. `Container` is from `SimpleInjector` which is compatible with `.NET Standard 2.0`.

```
public class AppUserManager : UserManager<AppUser>
{

    public AppUserManager(IUserStore<AppUser> store)
        : base(store)
    {

    }

    public static AppUserManager Create<AppContainer>() where AppContainer : Container, new()
    {
        var container = new AppContainer();
        var store = container.GetInstance<IUserStore<AppUser>>();

        var manager = new AppUserManager(store);

        manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<AppUser>(manager)
        {
            AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false
        };


        return manager;
    }
}
```

If the `EntityFramework NuGet` is installed in the shared library the warning below is present. We can't risk that.

> Package 'EntityFramework 6.2.0' was restored using
>   '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework
>   '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible
>   with your project.

I have read about why they put `IdentityUser` in the EF Library, `IdentityUser` is very EF specific. However it makes porting to `.NET Standard 2.0.` harder.

[Why is the IdentityUser class in the Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework namespace and not in the Core package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30835779/why-is-the-identityuser-class-in-the-microsoft-aspnet-identity-entityframework-n)

I have also read that `ASP.NET Core 2.0` have removed the base `IdentityUser` POCO (Plain Old CLR Object).

`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity` and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore` only has dependencies to `.NETStandard 2.0` and can be installed without a warning. Do we need to upgrade Entity Framework and Identity on ASP.NET to Core or is there another way to get it working with `.NET Standard`? Last step that we need to get it running.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/identity-2x?view=aspnetcore-2.1

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/efcore-and-ef6/side-by-side

Comment: this `EntityFramework 6.2.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1` will not start under linux, so if you need to run your website under linux, you need to switch from EF to EF core

Comment: @tym32167 Yes that is why we can't risk having it :)

Comment: so, what the question then? :)

Comment: @tym32167 Do we need to upgrade Entity Framework and Identity to Core or is there another way to get it working with .NET Standard? :)

Comment: [.NET Standard 2.0 is supported on the following platforms](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/08/14/announcing-net-standard-2-0/), so if you are using FW 4.6.1 - you can use .NET Standard 2.0 libraries

Comment: Incomplete question on my side. We would like to have the functionality in the .NET Standard Library and it will be used by both Framework AND Core.

Comment: I have 2 applications - one is WPF with FW 4.6.2, another one is asp.net core 2.1 - both of them using same .NET Standard 2.0 libraries with no problem

Comment: But then you don’t have IdentityUser in Standard 2.0 lib? See point 3 and 4 above

Comment: yep, I dont have `IdentityUser`, it is from .NET Core which is not compatible with FW 4.6.1 (afaik), so you cannot share it across project. I dont get why you wrote about `SimpleInjector` and how it is related to question, but you can only share .NET Standard libraries, and cannot share .NET Core  with full framework.

Comment: @tym32167 `SimpleInjector` was to describe what the inherited `Container` was in the code example. The text is long but if you read it all I think it is pretty clear what the problem is and where our problems are.

Comment: @Ogglas did you get it working in the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that we only need `EntityFramework 6.2.0` to work with both `.NET Framework` and `.NET Core` this will be solved in `.NET Core 3`.

> .NET Core 3 is a major update which adds support for building Windows
>   desktop applications using Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF),
>   Windows Forms, and Entity Framework 6 (EF6).

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/12/04/announcing-net-core-3-preview-1-and-open-sourcing-windows-desktop-frameworks/

Comment: How did `EntityFramework` solve that exactly? You cannot add a reference to to EntityFramework from a .net standard project...

Comment: @Albert Yes you can. EntityFramework 6.4.4 is compatible with .NETStandard 2.1. https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework#dependencies-body-tab
They did not solve the `.NET Framework` compatibility though since no `.NET Framework` is compatible with .NETStandard 2.1.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard?tabs=net-standard-2-1